# Use iptables chain to monitor traffic

Tags: iptables, network-monitoring

We have a linux box in use as a router, with various rules (ip, tcp port, udp port, etc.) in the iptables `FORWARD` chain, which might be added to or removed from at any time.

I need to monitor different aspects of the traffic going through the box, including tcp segments and udp datagrams separately.

`netstat -s` only outputs statistics for data originating from or directed to the router, and so I figured iptables itself would make more sense. I found [this explanation](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/traffic-accounting-with-iptables/) of how to send traffic from the `FORWARD` chain to a user-defined chain to monitor statistics, but it glossed over what the effect will be if there are already rules in the `FORWARD` chain.

My question is this: will inserting a rule to "redirect all the traffic going through the machine to match the rules in the [user-defined] chain" stop the traffic from getting processed by the rest of the `FORWARD` chain? In other words, if a packet hits the `FORWARD` chain and is redirected immediately to a user-defined chain just to monitor traffic, what will happen to that packet? Will it continue going through the rules in the `FORWARD` chain until it hits a rule to accept/drop the packet?

Comment: Why the downvote? Was the question not written clearly? I thought it could be helpful to someone else in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing some testing on a system that was not in a production environment. It turns out, you CAN use the user-defined traffic monitoring chain and it will not affect your current rules.

The packet will go through the user-defined chain, where it can be monitored, and it will still be accepted or blocked by the other rules in the `FORWARD` chain.